# How to catch signal in ESP8266 when someone rings (doorbell)

Tags: esp8266, component-selection

I'm actually a software developer and new to electronics and ESP8266 etc.

I want to learn electronics and my first project would be to catch the signal within ESP8266 when someone rings / uses the doorbell. The software is not the problem, but which electronic components do I need and which cables do I have to connect between doorbell and ESP?

I opened the case:
[image: doorbell]

Translations of the words on the board, if it helps:

- kirmizi = red
- mavi = blue
- beyaz = white
- KPC SASE (I don't know)
- sari = yellow
- pembe = pink
- gri = grey
- siyah = black
- zil = bell
- KPC HP (I don't know)

I just want send push notifications to my PC and smartphone and to light up a LED when someone rings on the door.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you disconnecting the device in the photo from the existing door bell system?

Comment: No. I will just put my ESP8266 on it. I thought I can connect my device with the existing door bell systems and cables.

Comment: Is that your own doorbell, or does it belong to whoever owns the building? But it does not matter, based on what you show, there is no way to determine how that thing is wired to do anything.

Comment: I bought this house.

Comment: use a microphone sensor in the box, tape over it if need to get detectable readings only when buzzing.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you. I did this now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do one of the LEDs illuminate when you press the button?  If so, you could possibly replace the LED with a suitable opto-isolator.  The output of the opto-isolator could then connect to your ESP.

Comment: When I press the bell button outside, yes, it's green then for a while. But it's also illuminate the LED when I press the button on this door bell system to open the front door.